# Convert Float to Int

Tags: c#

So I've got a project I'm working on. This is the only error I have:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'.

I understand somewhat what that means. I just need help converting my float to int.

This is just an example of one of the floats:

```
float key = 0.5f;
int key = 53;
```

Here's the specific code section:

```
// price in scrap, e.g. 29 / 9 = 3.33 ref
static int BuyPricePerTOD = 21;
// price in scrap, e.g. 31 / 9 = 3.55 ref
static float SellPricePerTOD = BuyPricePerTOD + 0.5F;

static int BuyPricePerKey = 53;
static float SellPricePerKey = BuyPricePerKey + 0.5F;

static int TimerInterval = 170000;
static int InviteTimerInterval = 2000;

int UserWeapAdded,UserScrapAdded,UserRecAdded,UserRefAdded,
    UserKeysAdded,UserTODAdded,BotTODsAdded,BotKeysAdded,
    BotScrapAdded,BotRecAdded,BotRefAdded,InventoryMetal,
    InventoryScrap,InventoryRec,InventoryRef,InventoryKeys,
    InventoryTOD,PreviousTODs,PreviousKeys,WhileLoop,InvalidItem = 0;

float UserMetalAdded, BotMetalAdded, OverpayNumKeys,
    OverpayNumTOD, ExcessInScrapKey, ExcessInScrapTOD = 0.0F;
double ExcessRefinedKey, ExcessRefinedTOD = 0.0;
```

Comment: Could you show some code that you have made so far?

Comment: @user3325320..  int _value=Convert.ToInt32(key);

Comment: Do you want to round? Or do you just want to truncate? For example `1.8` rounded is `2`, but truncated is `1`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pktckAYB   That is the section that needs converting.  Also the number needs to be exact. I can't round it or truncate. But then again im not using decimals.

Comment: @user3325320, `int`s can't store fractional values, hence the name *integer*

Comment: I am still so confused. I don't know how to get around this. That section i posted was a premade section to add to my project. I honestly don't get the .05f part. I just want to get rid of the float all together and make it an int. but obviously cannot.

Comment: @user3325320 the code you linked to adds 0.5 to the amount the f at the end just indicates that it is a float. If you start with an integer of 53 and you add half to it (=53.5), you need to store it as something that has decimal places (eg float, double or decimal). If you "just want to get rid of the float" then delete the code that added to the price. If you don't like putting "f" after values then use a double, it will happily do 53 + 0.5

Comment: `float key = 0.5f; int key = 53;` You cannot have the same defined name in one scope. You can use keyFloat and keyInt for example.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Firstly, there are *integers* and *floating-point* numbers. Integers are *always* whole numbers, such as `0`, `1`, `-32`, `42` and `1337`. On the other hand, floating-point numbers *can* have a fractional part: `0`, `1`, `-32.1`, `42.7` and `123.456788` are all valid floating-point numbers.

When converting between integers (`int`) and floating-point (`float`) numbers, you can do this:

```
int someInt = 42;
float someFloat = someInt;  // 42.0f
```

But you can't do this:

```
float someFloat = 42.7f;
int someInt = someFloat;    // ?
```

The reason the first conversion is possible, is that converting the integer number (`int`) to a floating-point number (`float`) does *not* change the number. It is a safe conversion, and therefore can be done *implicitly*.

The reason the second conversion is not allowed, is that converting the floating-point number (which may have a fractional part) to an integer number (that never has a fractional part) must drop the fractional part of the number, i.e. it becomes a different number. This is not safe, and can therefore only be done *explicitly*.

---

To explicitly convert one type of number to another, you use a *cast*. That's the parentheses before the number with the type of the number that you want to convert it to.

```
float someFloat = 42.7f;
int someInt = (int)someFloat;               // 42
```

Note that the fractional part of the floating-point number was dropped. It's as if it has been rounded towards zero. If you want to round the floating-point number to the nearest whole number, use the [`Math.Round` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx).

```
float someFloat = 42.7f;
int someInt = (int)Math.Round(someFloat);   // 43
```

Comment: 'rounded down towards zero' is an oxymoron. I mean this is not the same thing. Your explanation is ambiguous because 'rounding down' and 'rounding towards zero' are the opposite directions for negative numbers. they are the same thing for positive numbers.

Answer (score 14):

Try this :

```
int numInt = (int)Math.Ceiling(numFloat);
```

[msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You may want `Math.Round()` or `Math.Floor()` by the way.

Example :

```
float numFloat = 1.5f;
int testCeiling = (int)Math.Ceiling(numFloat);
int testFloor = (int)Math.Floor(numFloat);
int testRound = (int)Math.Round(numFloat);

Console.WriteLine("testCeiling = {0}", testCeiling.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("testFloor = {0}", testFloor.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("testRound= {0}", testRound.ToString());
```

output :

```
testCeiling = 2
testFloor = 1
testRound= 2
```