# How to convert flaot to int

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to implement a health bar in unity but I cant figure out how to convert a float to a int Ive been struggling a while know if I can get any help that would be amazing Im also using the new input system in unity

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Stats : CoreComponent
{
[SerializeField] private float maxHealth;
private float currentHealth;

public HealthBar healthBar;

protected override void Awake()
{
    base.Awake();

    currentHealth = maxHealth;
    healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
}

public void DecreaseHealth(float amount)
{
    currentHealth -= amount;
    healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        currentHealth = 0;
        Debug.Log("Health is zero!!");
    }
}

public void IncreaseHealth(float amount`
{
    currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth + amount, 0, maxHealth);
}
}
```

Comment: int x = (int)floatValue; also find more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896580/convert-float-to-int I assume this question is gonna get closed

Comment: Depends ... do you want to round ([`Mathf.RoundToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html), [`Mathf.FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html), [`Mathf.CeilToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.CeilToInt.html)) or just cut off the decimals (`(int) someFloatValue`) which basically equals `Mathf.FloorToInt` again?

Comment: I don't see though where exactly you would need an `int` in your code ...