# error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make some text display a price that changes by 5 present every time you press a button.
Sorry if i explain badly im new to stack and coding. Just ask me if you need more context.
This is unity using visual studio code c#.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class clicksUpPerSec : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Button addBut1PS;
  public GameObject ShowClickerPrice;
  public static int perSec = 0;
  public static float ClickerPrice = 10f;
  public float Prosent = 5f;

  void Start()
  {
      Button btn = addBut1PS.GetComponent<Button>();
  btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);

  }


  void Update() {
      
      ShowClickerPrice.GetComponent<Text>().text = "COST: " + ClickerPrice;
  }

  void TaskOnClick(){

      if(Click.clicks >= ClickerPrice) {
          perSec = perSec + 1;
          Click.clicks = Click.clicks - ClickerPrice;
          ClickerPrice = (((Prosent  * ClickerPrice) / 100f) + ClickerPrice);
      }
      
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Float to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896580/convert-float-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Click.clicks = Click.clicks - ClickerPrice;
```

Here you are trying to assing float value to an integer field and there is no implicit conversion for that, you need to cast (int) somewhere to convert value expilictly:

```
Clicks.clicks = Click.clicks - (int)ClickerPrice;
```

or

```
Click.clicks = (int)(Click.clicks - ClickerPrice);
```